# File upload using .fetch() in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload file using `.fetch()` in ReactJS as Front End and Laravel as Back End. My ReactJS code is like below

```
update= (event) => {
let uploadImage =  event.target.file;
let form = new FormData()
form.append('uploadImage',uploadImage)

fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses/upload', {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken(),
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  },
  method: "POST",
  body: form,
})
.then(response => response.json())
.catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
.then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
}
```

My Laravel code is like below

```
public function fileUpload(StoreImageRequest $request)
    {
        $image           = $request->uploadImage;
        $imagename       = time() . $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $destinationPath = public_path('/images');
        $uploadValue     = $image->move($destinationPath, $imagename);
        if ($uploadValue) {
            return response()->json($imagename);
        }
    }
```

I am getting error like below

[image]

and

[image]

[image]

Where is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you upload the image with form field name `avatar`, but in your Laravel method you access it with `uploadImage`.

So you can try change it to the following:

```
$request->avatar
```

Please checkout [the Laravel Files documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#files) and make sure you follow their best practices.

Comment: Thanks @Jordan Enev. But your solution is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by removing the content type.

Please check this article

https://upmostly.com/tutorials/upload-a-file-from-a-react-component